# How to handle if the parameter is in url is empty laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a `Route`-

```
/first/second/{param}, 'IndexController@index'
```

And in controller

```
public function index($param)
{
    $param = trim($param);
    if($param == "")
    {
        redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

I have tried to handle it but failed. When ever I send `/first/second/` if gives error of `RouteCollection`. How can I control it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please take some time to read the documentation a little bit: [Optional Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#parameters-optional-parameters)

> Occasionally you may need to specify a route parameter, but make the
>   presence of that route parameter optional. You may do so by placing a
>   `?` mark after the parameter name. Make sure to give the route's
>   corresponding variable a default value:
>
> ```
> Route::get('user/{name?}', function ($name = null) {
>     return $name;
> });
>
> Route::get('user/{name?}', function ($name = 'John') {
>     return $name;
> });
> ```

---

So, in your case, the route will be:

```
/first/second/{param?}, 'IndexController@index'
```

And in controller

```
public function index($param ='')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate your param as null in your function defintion

```
public function index($param = null) {
    if (!$param) {
         return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: why `null` if he checks for string?